# How to set constraints in Angular 8 routing with parameters

Tags: angular, parameters, routes, angular8, check-constraints

I'm setting up routes with parameters in my web application with Angular. How can I set constrains to those parameters ?

This is the path in my 'app-routing.module.ts' :

```
{path: 'post/:id', component: PostComponent, resolve: {resolver: Resolver}},
```

A user can change the URL in his browser and set any ID he'd like.

I would like to set a constraint to prevent that. I have and array of Posts, each Post with its own ID, and I want the routes available to be only those specific ID's. A non-existing ID would then redirect the user to 404.

Answer (score 0):

The way to restrain navigation is by the use of angular Guards, I would suggest you start with a [CanActivate guard](https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate)

```
{
  path: 'post/:id',
  component: PostComponent,
  resolve: {resolver: Resolver}},
  canActivate: [CanActivateId]
}
```

and the Guard can be (for starters just ids which are less then 10 as an example):

```
@Injectable()
class CanActivateId implements CanActivate {
  constructor() {}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<boolean|UrlTree>|Promise<boolean|UrlTree>|boolean|UrlTree {
    return route.params.id > 10;
  }
}
```